# Existence of a surjective function with certain characteristics

Tags: set-theory

Is it true that there is a surjective function $f:\omega_1 \to \omega_1 \times \omega_1$ such that, for every uncountable subset $S\subseteq \omega_1$, there are uncountable subsets $X,Y \subseteq \omega_1$ such that $X\times Y \subseteq f[S]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible for quite simple reasons:
For every surjective $f\colon\omega_1\to\omega_1\times \omega_1$, the set $f^{-1}(\{0\}\times \omega_1)$ is uncountable